# "No module named matplotlib" error in Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I open my anaconda virtual environment in this way (Linux)

```
source /home/sasha/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate gl-env (gl-env is my virtual environment)
pip3 install jupyter notebook
pip3 install matplotlib
pip3 install -U turicreate
jupyter notebook
```

After launching Jupiter, i see "No module named matplotlib" mistake, while turicreate is working normally.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You should probably use conda as noted below, but the other wild guess is that you do not have `pip3` installed in your env

Comment: Why use pip to install those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use pip with Anaconda.  Use conda instead. So you commands should have been:

```
conda install jupitor notebook

conda install matplotlib

conda install turicreate
```

You can check conda for the -U option.

Comment: To add on this this, anaconda will actually alias `pip` to whatever version of python you are using, so using `pip3` will not install on the anaconda environment